# Flexbox row and column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In desktop and tablet, I am currently trying to center my flexbox content and have each of my items have some space between, so that they are not so squished together. In mobile the items stack which is what I want but the words do not squish in the center enough so you can read them. I'll insert a snippet but you might have to make it full screen to see what I mean in both desktop and mobile. If you need me to explain further, please let me know. Thank you!

```css
#quotecontainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1DA0A3;
  flex-flow: row;
  max-width: 1700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#quotes {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#michelle {
  align-self: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#jerry {
  align-self: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  ;
}
#lighticon {
  align-self: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100px;
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  #quotes {
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="quotecontainer">
  <div id="quotes">
    <h3 id="michelle">"She always thinks of her clients."
<br>
-Michelle Houle

Connections FSE
</h3>

    <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/512/099310-feedburner-logo.png" alt="" id="lighticon" />

    <h3 id="jerry">"Very smart, creative person, problem solver."
<br>
-Jerry Nygard C2P

</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically you want to centre your content, right?

Comment: correct @anurag daolagajao